# How to get value from InterpolatingFunction

Tags: differential-equations, interpolation

I have numerically solved a system of ODEs using NDSolve. I can plot them using `ParametricPlot` but I am having trouble evaluating them at specific points and getting the derivative. For example, if `z0[s]` is the solution to one of my equations, I want `z0[2]` or `z0[3]`.

In [the help file](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingFunction.html) for `InterpolatingFunction`, their example seems trivial. They find the solution `ifun` of an ODE using `NDSolve` and then use the command `ifun[2.5]` to evaluate the function at 2.5. This is the functionality I want. I am having trouble seeing why this isn't working for my situation. Here is my code:

```
eq={(z0'')[s]==0,(z1'')[s]==0,(z2'')[s]==0,(z3'')[s]==0};
initCond={z1[0]==0,z0[0]==0,z2[0]==2,z3[0]==0,z0'[0]==1,z1'[0]==-1,z2'[0]==0,z3'[0]==0};
fullEq=Union[geoEq1,initCond1];
sol=NDSolve[fullEq,{z0[s],z1[s],z2[s],z3[s]},{s,0,20}]
```

Note that the systems of ODEs I use is very basic (the solution is just a straight line). I just want to learn how to do this for for a general function first.

This output

```
{{z0[s] -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 20.}}, <>][s], 
  z1[s] -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 20.}}, <>][s], 
  z2[s] -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 20.}}, <>][s], 
  z3[s] -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 20.}}, <>][s]}}
```

According to the help file, I think I should be able to do `z0[2]` to get the value and `z0'[2]` to get the value of the derivative. I try `z0[2]` and `z0[2] /. sol` but this doesn't yield the result.

For completeness, I have checked related questions on this SE but most seem to be for either a single `InterpolatingFunction` (i.e. not a system of 4 functions) and not for a parametrized solution `z0[s]`. I have not yet found any solution on the help file. I will keep looking and post back if I solve it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are basically, say, 2 x 2 = four forms of results one can extract from `NDSolve`, aside from some special-use cases.  I think one of these four tends to be more useful than the others, although occasionally I find the other forms useful in particular cases.  The one I like is based on a central idiom of *Mathematica*, the replacement [`Rule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html), and works well in *Mathematica*.  The idea is not common in other languages, and so some may tend to avoid it.  The one I like is also in terms of *functions* $f$ instead of an expression $f(x)$. Despite that everything is an expression in *Mathematica*, since we're doing calculus here, dealing in terms of functions plays to one of *Mathematica's* strengths.

The four forms can be viewed as the combinations of two binary divisions. The first division is the choice of the result as a rule or an expression:

```
NDSolve[eqns, u, {x, xmin, xmax}]        (* replacement rule *)
NDSolveValue[eqns, u, {x, xmin, xmax}]   (* function expression *)
  (* equiv. to u /. NDSolve[eqns, u, {x, xmin, xmax}] *)
```

The second is the form of `u`, either a function or the function-value at the dependent variable `x`; for instance

```
NDSolve[eqns, y, {x, xmin, xmax}]        (* (interpolating) function *)
NDSolve[eqns, y[x], {x, xmin, xmax}]     (* function-value at x *)
```

The one I like is

```
NDSolve[eqns, y, {x, xmin, xmax}]
```

which returns a rule of the form `y -> InterpolatingFunction[<>]` (inside lists, of course).  **This can be used to inject a function (the solution) into any expression.**  *Mathematica* will compute the rest, including any derivatives and integrals of `y` that appear in the expression.  This is the principal reason I like it.

By contrast

```
NDSolve[eqns, y[x], {x, xmin, xmax}]
```

returns a rule of the form `y[x] -> InterpolatingFunction[<>][x]`.  If it is applied to an expression, it will only replace `y[x]`, literally.  It will not replace `y[2.5]` or `y'[x]`, and so forth.  This is where the OP ran into trouble with his or her code.

**Example**

I'll use a slight modification of the OP's example.  I'll reduce the number of functions to `{z0, z1}` and use slightly more interesting DEs.
Often I find it is convenient to collect all the functions in the differential equation in a list such as `vars` below.  If `vars = {z0, z1}`, then `Through[vars[s]]` equals `{z0[s], z1[s]}`.  The solution `solIF` is in the form I prefer, `{z0 -> InterpolationFunction[<>],...}` and `solS` is in the form `{z0 -> InterpolationFunction[<>][s],...}`.

In another side note, the assignment `{solIF} =...` works if `eqs` are quasilinear system, because the solution will consist of a single set of functions for the dependent variables. If there is an error and `NDSolve` does not return a solution, the assignment will fail. One advantage over using `solIF = NDSolve[...]` is in code that uses `solIF` immediately: On the one hand, if `NDSolve` fails, `solIF` will equal the original `NDSolve[]` call, and every time `solIF` is evaluated, it leads to another failed evaluation of `NDSolve[]`. On the other hand, if the system is not quasilinear (and I expected it to be so) and `NDSolve` returns more than one set of solutions, then the assignment will fail.  This lets me knowing I wasn't thinking straight or that the system was not constructed properly. (It's a minor point, but I thought I should explain why I do it.)

```
(* damped/harmonic oscillators *)
eqs = {z0''[s] + z0'[s]/8 + z0[s] == 0, z1''[s] + 4 z1[s] == 0};
ics = {z0[0] == 0, z0'[0] == 1, z1[0] == 0, z1'[0] == -1};
vars = {z0, z1};
{solIF} = NDSolve[{eqs, ics}, vars, {s, 0, 20}]             (* z0 -> ifn, etc *)
{solS} = NDSolve[{eqs, ics}, Through[vars[s]], {s, 0, 20}]  (* z0 -> ifn[s], etc *)
```

To evaluate `z0` at `2.5`, say, here's how to use each form.  It is somewhat more straightforward with the `z0 -> InterpolatingFunction[<>]` form in `solIF`.

```
z0[2.5] /. solIF
z0[s] /. solS /. s -> 2.5
```

Computing the derivative `z1'[s]` is even more natural with `solIF`. In the function-value expression form (like the OP's), only the last form of the derivative of `z1` is computed correctly, since it is the only code in which the replacement rules are applied to `z1[s]`.

```
z1'[s] /. solS
D[z1[s], s] /. solS
D[z1[s] /. solS, s]
(*
  Derivative[1][z1][s]
  Derivative[1][z1][s]
  InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 20.}}, <>][s]
*)
```

By contrast, all three form work with the function form:

```
z1'[s] /. solIF
D[z1[s], s] /. solIF
D[z1[s] /. solIF, s]
```

Often, we use the solutions to perform other calculations.  For instance, we can examine the energy in the oscillator systems represented by `{eqs, ics}`.  Here is some code for computing the energy:

```
ClearAll[energy];

SetAttributes[energy, Listable];
energy[harmonicODE_, s0_] := Module[{z, s, m, γ, k},
   {{z, s}} = Cases[harmonicODE, Derivative[2][z_][s_] :> {z, s}, Infinity, 1];
   {k, γ, m} = Coefficient[harmonicODE /. Equal -> Subtract, {z[s], z'[s], z''[s]}];
   k z[s0]^2/2 + m z'[s0]^2/2
   ];

energy[eqs, s]
(*
  {z0[s]^2/2 + 1/2 z0'[s]^2, 
   2 z1[s]^2 + 1/2 z1'[s]^2}
*)
```

These are symbolic expressions for the energies.  We can evaluate them by injecting the solution functions in `solIF` into the energies and plugging in values for `s`, say, via `Plot[]`:

```
Plot[energy[eqs, s] /. solIF // Evaluate, {s, 0, 20}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I don't know a simple way to do that with `solS`.

I won't say much about `NDSolveValue[]`.  It returns `InterpolatingFunction[<>]` or  `InterpolatingFunction[<>][s]`.  It can be convenient if you just want to evaluate the function.  One can inject them in an expression by writing your own rules, but that can be a bit inconvenient if you have several variable `{z0, z1,...}` as in the OP's case.  You're probably better off using `NDSolve[]` in that case.

Comment: Excellent answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this, hopefully I have correctly fixed what I think where typos

```
geoEq1 = {z0''[s] == 0, z1''[s] == 0, z2''[s] == 0, z3''[s] == 0};
initCond1 = {z1[0] == 0, z0[0] == 0, z2[0] == 2, z3[0] == 0, 
  z0'[0] == 1, z1'[0] == -1, z2'[0] == 0, z3'[0] == 0};
fullEq = Union[geoEq1, initCond1];
{o0, o1, o2, o3} = {z0, z1, z2, z3} /. 
  NDSolve[fullEq, {z0, z1, z2, z3}, {s, 0, 20}][[1]];
Plot[{o0[s], o1[s], o2[s], o3[s]}, {s, 0, 20}]
{o0[1], o1[3], o2[2], o3[4]}
```

and you should see the four overlaid plots and four evaluations of your interpolating functions.

I used o0,o1,o2,o3 because I wasn't sure if you were going to need to maintain the original values of your zn assignments.

Note the [[1]] trailing the NDSolve to eliminate one extra layer of {}. Note the change in form of your zn inside the argument list to NDSolve. Note the way that each on is initialized and later used.

There are at least a dozen other ways of doing anything in Mathematica. Pick one that you can master and remember for next time.

Comment: You could use `NDSolveValue`.